# How to connect to tethering socks proxy?

Tags: proxy, tethering, socks

I've got socks proxy server running on iPhone, it is possible via Tethering app from Emu4iOS. iPhone connected to wifi hotspot and, as I can see in tethering app, connection is active. How can I connect to this proxy from Yosemite Mac wich connected to same hotspot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "System Preferences > Network", chose your WiFi connection and in "Advanced" options at "Proxies" tab check "SOCKS Proxy" and type your server's dress and port.
[image]

Also very important to uncheck "Use Passive FTP Mode (PASV)"